# Whole image should be clickable on "change picture" link

Tags: feature-request, profile-picture, user-experience

There is a related question: [Please make “change picture” link in profile take up the whole box it is inside of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164993/please-make-change-picture-link-in-profile-take-up-the-whole-box-it-is-inside)

But, my suggestion is that the **whole profile picture** / avatar **be clickable** instead of just the semi-transparent black overlay link.

Right now the profile picture is linked to the user's profile page, thus forwarding them to the page they're already on, a bad UX. It would be better if clicking anywhere on the image brought up the change picture dialog.

Comment: Agree, full avatar should be clickable other than only "change picture" transparent link.